# JSON-RPC binance smart chain получить список событий

Tags: blockchain, json-rpc

пытаюсь получить записи о событии PairCreated (https://bscscan.com/address/0xca143ce32fe78f1f7019d7d551a6402fc5350c73#events). Но на мой запрос сервер отвечает `{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":[]}`. Помогите правильно составить запрос к RPC.

```
curl https://bsc-dataseed1.ninicoin.io/ -X POST --data '{               
    "id": 1,
    "method": "eth_getLogs",
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "params": [
            {
    "address": "0xca143ce32fe78f1f7019d7d551a6402fc5350c73",
    "topics": ["0x0d3648bd0f6ba80134a33ba9275ac585d9d315f0ad8355cddefde31afa28d0e9"]
            }
    ]}'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По умолчанию метод выдает список событий для последнего блока цепочки. Надо указать некий диапазон анализируемых блоков, использую тэги "fromBlock", "toBlock".

Можно, например, попробовать "fromBlock":"0x1", "toBlock":"latest" - тогда, по идее, должно пройти по всей цепочке.

Comment: а вы случаем не можете подсказать как получить fromBlock для контракта? Есть какой-то метод для этого? А то там стоит лимит не более 5000 блоков на обработку за раз

Comment: Если есть идентификатор транзакции, то номер блока, в который она была включена можно получить по методу eth_getTransactionReceipt - тэг blockNumber. Если ответ будет пустой - значит транзакция ещё в очереди. 
Или можно просто перед вбросом транзакции зафиксировать последний номер блока (eth_blockNumber) и потом от него искать.